# How to manage datetime in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, datetime, momentjs

I'm working with Angular(v5).
I have some problem with Datetime.

I need the current time and I have to save it in a variable. After that I have to subtract an interval of hours (8 hours or an hour) and save the result in a variable and then do it with`console.log`.

I need the format to be: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`

I tried to integrate `moment.js` without fail but I always get errors in the console, how can I solve?

I upload my [code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-momentjs-datetime)

is there a way to manage datetime in angular simply?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your import statement is incorrect
change statement to:

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

your desired format can be achieved with the following statement:

```
time.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```

I forked your code and added the formating and your time calculation functions:
**[time format example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-momentjs-datetime-csygqd?file=app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: thanks a lot, I was following wrong answer on stackoverflow.

Comment: @NicolòScapin if this answer helped you consider accepting it

Answer (score 5):

You can just use the Date object, 
to get current Date you can use something like

```
const dateNow = new Date();
```

to subtract just do something like this

```
const dateNowMinusEightHours = new Date(new Date(dateNow).getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 8)
```

there's no need to import moment.js for simplistic use and manipulation of Dates.

Answer (score 1):

after correcting import statement you can subtract time and can format it as 
`console.log(moment().subtract(9,'hours').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:
Consider, you are fetching some kind of date from a json file in the following  format **"dt":1517216400,**

Now in the ts file of the component you want to fetch that data and change that into readable date format. Then you should follow this approach:

**

```
> let alldates = res['list'].map(res => res.dt)
>     alldates.forEach((res) => {
>         let jsdate = new Date(res * 1000)
>         weatherDates.push(jsdate.toLocaleTimeString('en', { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric' }))
>     })
```

**

Here, I've fetched the date present inside the list. Then applied the toLocaleTimeString() function to change into the format which I wanted.

Hope it helps,
Cheers

Comment: such complexity is unnecessary to achieve basic usage with dates

Answer (score 0):

The correct import is

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
# Or 
import moment from 'moment';
```